# Open Graph Metadata for Foursquare

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph, foursquare

Is it possible when integrating with the [save to foursquare](https://foursquare.com/business/brands/offerings/savetofoursquare) api to use only Open Graph Data?

The foursquare API states:

> In order for the Save to foursquare button to work on your site, your site should include hCard or OpenGraph location metadata so that foursquare knows which place your web page is referring to.

However when I load my page with the following data:

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:latitude" content="40.707992194260186"/>
    <meta property="og:longitude" content="-74.05560369801627"/>
    <meta property="og:street-address" content="222 Jersey City Blvd."/>
    <meta property="og:locality" content="Jersey City"/>
    <meta property="og:region" content="NJ"/>
    <meta property="og:postal-code" content="07305"/>
    <meta property="og:country-name" content="USA"/>
</head>
```

as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

I get "No matching venues were found for this page." from https://foursquare.com/business/brands/offerings/savetofoursquare/tester

I believe I should receive the following venue: https://foursquare.com/v/liberty-science-center/4bf2e2fa6991c9b66e9f29e9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give some additional information (see required [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) fields), esp. a title:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Liberty Science Center" />
<meta property="og:type" content="landmark" />
<meta property="og:latitude" content="40.707992194260186" />
<meta property="og:longitude" content="-74.05560369801627" />
<meta property="og:street-address" content="222 Jersey City Blvd" />
<meta property="og:locality" content="Jersey City" />
<meta property="og:region" content="NJ" />
<meta property="og:postal-code" content="07305" />
<meta property="og:country-name" content="USA" />
<meta property="og:phone_number" content="201-200-1000" />
```

This should point to [Liberty Science Center](https://foursquare.com/v/liberty-science-center/4bf2e2fa6991c9b66e9f29e9).

Comment: I guess it makes sense, but just to double check.. there is basically no way the button api can select the most likely venue for me correct?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to specify a certain venue. The API will chose one for you.

Comment: I think you get the selection experience with hCard but use of og is indicating that the resource is exclusively about a specific location. I'll update after some more testing.